# How many T'fachim  make up an Ama?

Tags: number, shiurim-measurements

Is it possible to convert between Torah measurements?

Specifically, T'fachim & Amot, (cubits) so I can figure out the size of the luchot (tablets) within the Aron Hakodesh (ark). (The Luchot are 6x6x3 t'fachim each [6 t'fachim cubed together] & the ark is 1.5 x 2.5x 1.5 cubits)

Comment: You are asking 3 different questions. Please specify which is your primary intention: How many _t'fachim_ are there in an _ama_? Can one convert between _Biblical_ linear measurements (for not all _t'fachim_ are biblical)? How much space did the _luchos_ take up in the _aron kodesh_? Also see [here](http://www.come-and-hear.com/bababathra/bababathra_14.html) on that last point.

Comment: I edited to address your comments.

Comment: 4.5 according to wolframalpha. Though the gemara mentions 5 & 6. 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+cubit+in+handbreadths

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1handbreadth+in+cubits  it appears that hands and cubits are initially determined by inches, which means its not an ammah and a tefach.

Comment: there seems to be some error in your math.. 6x6x3 != 6

Comment: no error - each one is 6x6x3, (area = 108 t'fachim), there are two, so the total area is 216 t'fachim, or 6 cubed t'fachim when they are put together (216).

Answer (score 6):

There are two types of Amos: 5 tefach amos, 6 tefach amos. There are also "Sad" and "Happy" (if the tefach is with fingers stuck together or a bit loose) [which are different by 1/2 finger](http://books.google.com/books?id=SNT0uejJbBUC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=tefach+in+an+ammah&source=bl&ots=oZr1F_0cUb&sig=DzUIwApzyymwkOXar73JcMLB9s0&hl=en&ei=xMI5ToimOYPniALIid3RDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Nowadays, calculating biblical sizes has such a wide margin of error (in addition to the "niskatnu habeitzim" debate), that most numbers that are given for tfachim/ammah are rounded lchumra. According to R' A"H Naeh, a tefach is 8cm.

http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=3b&format=text

Comment: Which way is lechumra?

Answer (score 5):

The gemara in [Bava Batra 14a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=14&format=pdf) addresses the exact issue you seem to be inquiring about.

There is a Tanaic dispute as to how many tefachim are in a biblical amah:

- **R' Meir-** 6 tefachim = 1 amah
- **R' Yehuda-** 5 tefachim = 1 amah

The gemara then procceeds to evaluate the geometry involved with the Aron and its contents.